# Run debian graphical installer from within debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, dual-boot, debian-installer

Is there a way to execute the debian graphical installer from the debian system that i'm currently running?

I would like to install another debian system in a second partition but i cannot make a bootable usb drive with the debian netinst installer in it.

Comment: Yes it is possible to install debian from an existing linux install (dual boot) through chroot and debootstarp but without gui

Comment: Not sure why this question is marked as unclear. My question is very direct and the selected answer dealt with it in the most straightforward way possible.

Answer (score 4):

The expected way to install Debian to another partition from within a running Debian system is to use [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). You'll need to format the partition manually and mount it first, then just run `debootstrap` with the options to install the Debian version you want along with whatever packages you want (for example, `--include=kde-plasma-desktop`).

`chroot` into it, [configure it and install a kernel and some other tools](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apds03.html.en). From your primary partition set up your boot manager (e.g. `grub`). Then you should be able to boot into your new partition.

Comment: Ty, this settles it for anybody looking for the standard way. Personally however, i won't even touch the `debootstrap` procedure with a stick, i'll get a functioning usb drive instead.